# Escaping new line character in a CSV output using Logstash

Tags: csv, escaping, logstash

I have the following logstash template that reads from a mysql database and outputs into a csv file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => ...
        jdbc_user => ...
        jdbc_validate_connection => ...
        jdbc_password => ...
        jdbc_driver_library => ...
        jdbc_driver_class => ...
        jdbc_paging_enabled => ...
        jdbc_page_size => "1000"
        statement => "SELECT name, age, bio FROM person"
    }
}
output {
      csv{
            fields => ["name", "age", "bio"]
            path => "output.csv"
      }
}
```

That works fairly good. However, `bio` field can have line breaks, which mess my CSV output. I've tried to use a filter/mutate transformation as:

```
filter{
      mutate
      {
          gsub => ["bio", "\n", "LINE_BREAK"]
      }
}
```

But it does not work. How can I have this field escaped?

**UPDATE**

I found the solution. Although it was impossible to diagnose from my original question. The missing information was that I am using a table ALIAS:

```
SELECT P.name, P.age, P.bio FROM person P
```

So, the filter was:

```
filter{
      mutate
      {
          gsub => ["P.bio", "\n", "LINE_BREAK"]
      }
}
```

For some reason logstash cannot identify this. So, the solution was to add an alias to the field:

```
SELECT P.name as name, P.age, P.bio as bio FROM person P

filter{
      mutate
      {
          gsub => ["bio", "\n", "LINE_BREAK"]
      }
}
```

**ps: those are not the originals tables/fields. The actual query is way longer and complicated. That is the reason that I am using table aliases**

Comment: Is your bio field correctly surrounded by double quotes?

Comment: @Val, yes. It is.

Comment: Ok, then you can correctly open that CSV file, right? What are you doing with it after it's been produced and why the newlines are an issue?

Comment: @Val, my mistake. I've updated the question.

Comment: Cool, so you're all good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think logstash can cope with the `'.'`, maybe you should use the `[]` notation.

```
filter{
      mutate
      {
          gsub => ["P.bio", "\n", "LINE_BREAK"]
      }
}
```

should be

```
filter{
      mutate
      {
          gsub => ["[P][bio]", "\n", "LINE_BREAK"]
      }
}
```